# Create multiple rules in AWS security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I tried to create an AWS security group with multiple inbound rules, Normally we need to multiple ingresses in the sg for multiple inbound rules. Instead of creating multiple ingress rules separately, I tried to create a list of ingress and so that I can easily reuse the module for different applications.

PFB,

module/sg/sg.tf >>

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_security_groups" {
  name   = var.name_security_groups
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}
```

module/sg/rules.tf >>

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rules" {
  count             = lenght(var.ingress_rules)
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = var.ingress_rules[count.index][0]
  to_port           = var.ingress_rules[count.index][1]
  protocol          = var.ingress_rules[count.index][2]
  cidr_blocks       = var.ingress_rules[count.index][3]
  description       = var.ingress_rules[count.index][4]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.ec2_security_groups.id
}
```

module/sg/variable.tf >>

```
variable "vpc_id" {
}
variable "name_security_groups" {
}
variable "ingress_rules" {
    type = list(string)
}
```

In the application folder,

application/dev/sg.tf >>

```
module "sg_test" {
  source = "../modules/sg"

  vpc_id                   = "vpc-xxxxxxxxx"
  name_security_groups = "sg_test"
  ingress_rules                     = var.sg_ingress_rules 
}
```

application/dev/variable.tf >>

```
variable "sg_ingress_rules" {
    type        = list(string)
    default     = {
        [22, 22, "tcp", "1.2.3.4/32", "test"]
        [23, 23, "tcp", "1.2.3.4/32", "test"]
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Missing attribute value

  on test-sgs.tf line 21, in variable "sg_ingress_rules":
  20: 
  21: 
  22: 

Expected an attribute value, introduced by an equals sign ("=").
```

Please help to correct this or if there is any other method please suggest.

Regards,

Comment: Your data structure doesn't make sense. If you want it to be a list of maps you could have something like `[{from_port: 22, to_port: 22, protocol: "tcp", cidr_range: "1.2.3.4/32", description: "test"}, {from_port: 23, to_port: 23, protocol: "tcp", cidr_range: "1.2.3.4/32", description: "test"}]`. But right now you have a broken map with no keys. You'd need to change up how you access it too. Alternatively you could have a list of lists to keep how you are accessing it but that's less descriptive to me.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR for the reply,

i tried with locals as well :-

locals {
  sg_ingress_rules = [
    { from_port = 80, to_port = 80, protocol = tcp, cidr_blocks = "1.2.3.4/32", description = "test" },
    { from_port = 443, to_port = 443, protocol = tcp, cidr_blocks = "1.2.3.4/32", description = "test" },
    { from_port = 22, to_port = 22, protocol = tcp, cidr_blocks = "1.2.3.4/32", description = "test" },
  ]
}

am getting the error:-

A managed resource "locals" "sg_egress_rules" has not been declared in the
root module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks@apparentlymart, who helped to solve this in Terraform discussion

The Security rule:-

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rules" {
  count = length(var.ingress_rules)

  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = var.ingress_rules[count.index].from_port
  to_port           = var.ingress_rules[count.index].to_port
  protocol          = var.ingress_rules[count.index].protocol
  cidr_blocks       = [var.ingress_rules[count.index].cidr_block]
  description       = var.ingress_rules[count.index].description
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.ec2_security_groups.id
}
```

And the variable:

```
variable "sg_ingress_rules" {
    type = list(object({
      from_port   = number
      to_port     = number
      protocol    = string
      cidr_block  = string
      description = string
    }))
    default     = [
        {
          from_port   = 22
          to_port     = 22
          protocol    = "tcp"
          cidr_block  = "1.2.3.4/32"
          description = "test"
        },
        {
          from_port   = 23
          to_port     = 23
          protocol    = "tcp"
          cidr_block  = "1.2.3.4/32"
          description = "test"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this in a simple way:-

```
locals {
  ports_in = [
    443,
    80
  ]
  ports_out = [
    0
  ]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "internet_facing_alb" {
  name        = "internetfacing-loadbalancer-sg"
  description = "Security group attached to internet facing loadbalancer"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = toset(local.ports_in)
    content {
      description = "Web Traffic from internet"
      from_port   = ingress.value
      to_port     = ingress.value
      protocol    = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }
  dynamic "egress" {
    for_each = toset(local.ports_out)
    content {
      description = "Web Traffic to internet"
      from_port   = egress.value
      to_port     = egress.value
      protocol    = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "internetfacing-loadbalancer-sg"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to implement multiple rules in a security group looks a bit like the following example:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sg_my_security_group" {
  name        = "sg_my_security_group"
  description = "Implements some security"
  vpc_id      = var.your_vpc_id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 3889
    to_port     = 3889
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 3889
    to_port     = 3889
    protocol    = "udp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "does_something_important"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to work literally with indexed fields, make it a **list(list(string))** and change the default oyter syntax from braces (used for maps) to brackets (used for lists):

```
variable "sg_ingress_rules" {
    type        = list(list(string))
    default     = [
        [22, 22, "tcp", "1.2.3.4/32", "test"]
        [23, 23, "tcp", "1.2.3.4/32", "test"]
    ]
}
```

That is a confusing data structure and will be difficult to work with, so I recommend this instead:

```
variable "sg_ingress_rules" {
    type        = map(map(any))
    default     = {
        thing1 = {from=22, to=22, proto="tcp", cidr="1.2.3.4/32", desc="test"}
        thing2 = {from=23, to=23, proto="tcp", cidr="1.2.3.4/32", desc="test"}
    }
}
```

You can use better names than the terrible ones I've chosen and then refer to them in your resource:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rules" {
  for_each          = var.ingress_rules
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = each.value.from
  to_port           = each.value.to
  protocol          = each.value.proto
  cidr_blocks       = each.value.cidr
  description       = each.value.desc
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.ec2_security_groups.id
}
```

You'll get multiple named copies of the aws_security_group_rule which better survives insertions and deletions from the ingress_rules variable and will save you headaches. Otherwise you'll get superfluous destroys and creates of rules and sometimes conflicts due to the indexed resources a count creates.

If you are feeling like having some better guardrails on people setting the ingress_rules value you can use object to require and restrict to a particular set of fields with certain types as follows:

```
variable "sg_ingress_rules" {
    type        = map(object(
      {
        from = number
        to = number
        proto = string
        cidr = string
        desc = string
      }
    ))
    default     = {
        thing1 = {from=22, to=22, proto="tcp", cidr="1.2.3.4/32", desc="test"}
        thing2 = {from=23, to=23, proto="tcp", cidr="1.2.3.4/32", desc="test"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks@Alain

I Tried this getting error "Error: Invalid multi-line string

  on ../modules/sgs/variable.tf line 136, in variable "sg_ingress_rules":
 136: 

Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines. To produce a multi-line
string, either use the \n escape to represent a newline character or use the
"heredoc" multi-line template syntax."

Answer (score 2):

There is a new way to manage multiple ingress rules, with a new terraform resource, named `aws_security_group_rule`

it is better than the other ways, using [Attributes as Blocks](https://www.terraform.io/language/attr-as-blocks)

Sample for reference

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "example" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 65535
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = [aws_vpc.example.cidr_block]
  ipv6_cidr_blocks  = [aws_vpc.example.ipv6_cidr_block]
  security_group_id = "sg-123456"
}
```

Ref: [aws_security_group_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule)

Comment: By far the simplest of all the other answers!